# JavaScript Regex: Match "-" only if a digit is followed by "-", but not match when there is only single "-"

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the trailing hyphen, but using the expression `[0-9]|-$` matches even if the string contains only one hyphen. How can I correct it?

Existing behavior

1. `-` #match (incorrectly working for me)
2. `-5-` #matching trailing hyphen only (correctly working for me)

Expected behavior

1. `-` #shouldn't match
2. `5-` #should match trailing hyphen (only "-" not whole "5-" )

Comment: You may use: `/(?<=[0-9])-/g`

Comment: It worked. Can you make it an answer? @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava On an unrelated note, /[á-ý]/ => this surrogate pair regex matches for the string é even without any /u flag. While the docs suggest the other way that /u is required. Why so?

Comment: Indeed that is matching without `/u` in multiple browsers I tried. May be it can become a good new question to ask on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind in Javascript to assert presence of a digit behind a hyphen using this regex:

```
/(?<=[0-9])-/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lkiV4g/1)

Comment: Since we can't polyfill, how can it be made work in Safari or any other pre ES2018 browsers which doesn't support positive lookbehind

Comment: If lookbehind is not supported then use either of these work arounds: `/\d-/g` or `^(?=.*\d(-))`